# Error linking 2 pages in React "Can not read push of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, button, push, router

I have built a web app to React. I have tried to link from Modeling page to the Upload Page by a button "Go" in the Modeling tab, there is an error for reading the property 'push' of undefined when I push to Upload.jsx
My modeling.jsx code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap"

class Modeling extends Component {

  uploadButton = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: "/upload"
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="modeling">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="about-text">
              <h2>3D MODELING</h2>
            </div>
          </div>       
              <Button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary go-button"
                onClick={this.uploadButton}
              >
                Go
              </Button>            
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Modeling;
```

App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "./components/navigation";
import Header from "./components/header";
import About from "./components/about";
import Modeling from "./components/modeling";
import Resources from "./components/resources";
import Team from "./components/Team";
import Upload from "./components/upload";
import JsonData from "./data/data.json";

export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    landingPageData: {}
  };
  getlandingPageData() {
    this.setState({ landingPageData: JsonData });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getlandingPageData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation />
        <Header data={this.state.landingPageData.Header} />
        <About data={this.state.landingPageData.About} />
        <Modeling data={this.state.landingPageData.Modeling} />
        <Resources data={this.state.landingPageData.Resources} />
        <Team data={this.state.landingPageData.Team} />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Navigation} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/modeling" component={Modeling} />
          <Route path="/upload" component={Upload} />
          <Route path="/resource" component={Resources} />
          <Route path="/team" component={Team} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-zjm5m?file=/src/components/modeling.jsx:0-809

Can someone stop by and give me some help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could either pass props from the parent or just use a `withRouter` HoC to be able to push history.

```
export default withRouter(Modeling);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-forked-dlrdo?file=/src/components/modeling.jsx

Comment: It does not link to the upload page. Could you try again?

Comment: @Sunny Of course it does - check the url. After clicking on "go upload" the url updates.

Comment: the url ./upload but why it does not link the page upload.jsx? it is should be what I want

Comment: @Sunny because the button which has the "Go Upload" button (Modelling) is not rendered within the `<Router>` tree so the `withRouter` is not in the right context, eg the history change is not happening as you want it!

Comment: so how can I fix this? since I want the user click the button to link to the page Upload.jsx

Comment: @Sunny make sure the `<Router>` component wraps everything. In your App.js making the `<Router>` the outer most component, wrapping everything should probably get you started. Currently you render some component outside of it. So when child components of those try to use the router you will run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your sandbox and you're not using the react-router Link component, in your navigation component, update your regular  links to use the Link component:

```
<ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <Link to="/" className="page-scroll">
      Home
    </Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="about" className="page-scroll">
      About
    </Link>
   </li>
   <li>
     <Link to="modeling" className="page-scroll">
       Modeling
     </Link>
   </li>
   <li>
     <Link to="resources" className="page-scroll">
      Resources
     </Link>
   </li>
   <li>
     <Link to="team" className="page-scroll">
      Team
     </Link>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Notice how I'm using the Link component which you can include using this import:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

After that your page should be working, remember that the to property should not use to='#modeling' because that is not the right syntax for the link component.

Also you can refactor your code a bit, mostly where you have the router part, take a look at my forked sandbox of your code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-forked-mugyc

Comment: sorry, but when I clicked to the link, nothing displayed except the name of project

Comment: Try the new one: https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-forked-mugyc

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a few different problems.

**1. Missing `history` prop.**

For a class component this can be solved by using the [`withRouter()`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) high order component. (For a functional component I'd recommend using the [`useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook to get access to the push api.)

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

In your *modeling.jsx* update the export to

```
export default withRouter(Modeling);
```

Remember to add an import at the top for `withRouter`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

**2. Page not updating once navigating.**

The component which has the *Go* button is not within the render tree of your `<Router>` component. So even after adding the `withRouter` HoC the page will only update the URL and not render the correct page.

In your *App.js* you could update to something like:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navigation />
          <Header data={this.state.landingPageData.Header} />

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Navigation} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/modeling" component={Modeling} />
            <Route path="/upload" component={Upload} />
            <Route path="/resources" component={Resources} />
            <Route path="/team" component={Team} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

**3. Your links in the Navigation component are using `<a>` tags.**

When using react-router you can use the [Link Component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link):

```
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <Link to="/" className="page-scroll">
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about" className="page-scroll">
              About
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/modeling" className="page-scroll">
              Modeling
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/resources" className="page-scroll">
              Resources
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/team" className="page-scroll">
              Team
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Remember to add an import for the `Link` component

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Example code sandbox update: https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-forked-yult1